# How to get an object's full name and "path" in a Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, object

Suppose I have a big SPA whose source I can look into. Now there's an object somewhere in there that contains data that I want to look at and/or change for debugging purposes.

I can put a `console.log(myObject)` in the code and it gets shown in the console, which is nice... but how can I output the complete *path* or *full name* of the object in the current window, so that I can open a JS console and enter for example:

`window.myApp.something.anothersomthing[12].myObject`

and then get my object? All I could find is how to print the type, but that doe not help. Any ideas?

Comment: A lot of times, the path you want is impossible (if for example `something` is a function the object won't be global so a path that begin with `window` is impossible as the object is only defined within the scope of the function)!

Comment: Equally there may be multiple paths to the same object. Or there may be cycles in the object graph. The graph is not a simple singular tree nor a DAG.

Comment: Good point, ibrahim, that's true. But let's assume for now that the object path *exists*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a a very naive implementation that lets you search an object graph for an object and print out the paths at which this object is encountered.

There are a number of caveats:

1. As you can see in the snippet, I pass in `window.myApp` as the context to initiate the search from. If you would pass in `window`, you'll run into a number of errors.
   For example, in Chrome, `window.clientInformation.plugins[0] === window.clientInformation.plugins[0]` evaluates to false, which makes keeping track of already visited objects impossible.
2. There's a number of implementation details that can cause the script below to misbehave (getters, proxies, generators, ...).

```js
function search(object, context) {
  let found = [];
  let visited = [];

  let visit = (object, reference, path) => {
    if (object === reference) {
      found.push(path);
    }

    if (!visited.includes(reference)) {
      visited.push(reference);

      if (Array.isArray(reference)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < reference.length; i++) {
          visit(object, reference[i], path + '[' + i + ']');
        }
      } else if (reference === Object(reference)) { // test for object
        for (let key in reference) {
          visit(object, reference[key], path + '.' + key);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  visit(object, eval(context), context);

  return found;
}

// example
let myObject = {};
let myApp = {
  something: {
    anotherSomething: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, {
      myObject: myObject
    }]
  }
};

window.myApp = myApp;

console.log(search(myObject, 'window.myApp'));
```